# Calculating improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

Does anyone know how to solve the following integral:

$$I =\int_{0}^\infty \cos(t \mathrm{log}( x))\,\mathrm{e}^{-ax}\, \mathrm{d}x,$$

where $t$ and $a$ are real.

Please show some intermediate steps if you can.

Thank you.

Comment: why do you mention $i$? how does it relate to your question?

Comment: @upol94  check out the relations on this Wolfram site http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
J = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a x} \, x^{\mu} \, dt = \frac{\Gamma(\mu+1)}{a^{\mu+1}}.
\end{align}
Let $\mu = i t$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$, for which
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a x} \, x^{i t} \, dt &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a x} \, e^{i t \ln(x)} \, dt = \frac{\Gamma(i t+1)}{a^{it+1}}
\end{align}
From this it is seen that
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(t \, \ln(x) ) \, e^{-a x} \, dx &= \mathcal{R}\left( \frac{\Gamma(i t+1)}{a^{it+1}}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \mathcal{R} \left( e^{-i t \ln(a)} \, \Gamma(i t + 1) \right)
\end{align}

Comment: My understanding is the first integral result comes using integration by parts and when $\mu$ is real and positive. Integration by parts can not be applied when $\mu$ is complex. I dont think you can simply write second integral from the $J$ when $\mu$ is complex. Can you please justify ?

Comment: In the integral for the Gamma function, namely, \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{z-1} \, dt \end{align} it is required that $\mathcal{R}(z) > 0$. In this integral $z$ can be $z = x + i y$.